# JavaScript (Node.js) interprets String contents as an Object on Linux Node only

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, string, typeerror

I'm having trouble with my Discord.io bot. I'm trying to get it running on a Linux server, however, the Linux version of Node.js constantly interprets the contents of a string as a seperate object, resulting in the following TypeError:

`TypeError: Object IT'S ALIVE has no method 'startsWith'
    at DiscordClient.bot.getMessages.channel (/root/Davixxabots/Daru/Darubot.js:182:17)
    at DiscordClient.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at DiscordClient.handleWSMessage (/root/Davixxabots/Daru/node_modules/discord.io/lib/index.js:1049:11)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Receiver.ontext (/root/Davixxabots/Daru/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:841:10)
    at /root/Davixxabots/Daru/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:536:18
    at Receiver.applyExtensions (/root/Davixxabots/Daru/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:371:5)
    at /root/Davixxabots/Daru/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:508:14
    at Receiver.flush (/root/Davixxabots/Daru/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:347:3)
    at Receiver.opcodes.1.finish (/root/Davixxabots/Daru/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:541:12)`

And the following is the code with said error:

```
if (message.toString().startsWith("/gamechange ") && userID == config.ownerID) {



                        //messageSplit = message.split("/gamechange");
                        var messageSplit = message.substring(message.indexOf("/gamechange ")+ 11);

                        if (messageSplit == "" || messageSplit == " ") {

                            bot.setPresence({ game:""});

                        }

                    bot.setPresence({

                            game: messageSplit

                    });

                    deleteCmdMessage(channelID, message);
                    log("Changed game to: \" " + messageSplit + ".");



            }
```

It is working perfectly fine on Windows.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: *"...constantly interprets the contents of a string as a seperate object,"* Don't know what you mean by that, but since your string doesn't have a `startsWith()` method, seems like you're just using an old version of node.

Comment: It was indeed an apparently very outdated version of Node.js running, as I had installed it from the default repos, it hadn't been maintained. It works now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> "...constantly interprets the contents of a string as a seperate object," Don't know what you mean by that, but since your string doesn't have a startsWith() method, seems like you're just using an old version of node.

As @squint pointed out in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383703/javascript-node-js-interprets-string-contents-as-an-object-on-linux-node-only/38396555#comment64177334_38383703), the issue was an outdated version of Node.js.